# An empirical central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory

I want to prove the following CLT:

> Let $(X_n)_{n}$ be i.i.d random variables with $\mathbb EX_1=0$ and $\mathbb E(X_1^2)<\infty$, then 
>   $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}} \longrightarrow_{d} N(0,1) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$

My idea: By the classical CLT, we have $S_n/\sqrt{n} \longrightarrow_{d} N(0,\sigma^2)$. Naively, I want to show that $$\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}}{n^{1/2}}$$ converge to a constant and use [the Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) to conclude (*). Is this idea working? How to I continue?

Comment: No, $\sqrt{\sum X_i^2}/n^{3/2}\to 0$.  Try $\sqrt{\sum X_i^2}/n^{1/2}$ instead.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea works indeed, but we need to change things a little bit. Denote $E(X_1^2)=\sigma^2\in (0,\infty).$

Notice that by the SLLN
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n} \to \sigma^2 \ \ \ \text{ a.s.}$$
Now define $Y_n$ as follows:$$Y_n:=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n}}$$
Notice that $Y_n\to \sigma$ almost surely. Now one has
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} {\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2} }=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} {\sqrt{n} \sigma} \cdot \frac{\sigma} {Y_n} $$
You see how you should apply Slutsky's theorem now?

*Oh, by the way almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.*

Comment: @manooooh there are different notions of convergence when we are dealing with random variables. This might help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables